# Why wont my program read the largest number?

Tags: c++, numbers

I am new to C++ so bear with me please. I know this is a very beginner problem. 
I am supposed to have the user input a number. Ex: 4. This is how many numbers we will read through and find the largest. My program allows the user to input a number and then list 4 integers. When I print out the largest number, it is not the largest one. If anyone could explain what I am doing wrong, that would be much appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    float largest;
    float max_input;
    float total = 0;
    float input;

myDefault:  
    cout << "Enter a positive number to start: ";
    cin >> max_input;

    if (max_input >= 0)
    {
        total++;


            do {
                cout << "Enter integer: ";
                cin >> largest;

                    if (largest >= 0)
                        {
                        total++;

                            if (input > largest)
                            {
                            input = largest;
                            }

                }
                }while (total <= max_input);

                cout << "\nThe largest number you entered is: " << largest << ".\n\n";

    }

    else 
    {
        cout << "Error. Enter a Positive number to start. \n";
        goto myDefault;

    }

    return (0);

    }
```

Comment: You're not initializing the variable input.

Comment: Your compiler almost certainly warned you about uninitialized variables. Do not ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    float largest = 0;
    float max_input;
    float total = 0;
    float input;

myDefault:  
    cout << "Enter a positive number to start: ";
    cin >> max_input;

    if (max_input >= 0)
    {
        total++;
        do {
            cout << "Enter integer: ";
            cin >> input;

            if (input >= 0)
            {
                total++;

                if (input > largest)
                {
                    largest = input;
                }
            }

        } while (total <= max_input);

        cout << "\nThe largest number you entered is: " << largest << ".\n\n";
    }

    else 
    {
        cout << "Error. Enter a Positive number to start. \n";
        goto myDefault;
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Here you are storing `input` in `largest`, checking if the next user input is larger than the largest.

Comment: Yeah this is what i came up with after reading the other problems. A problem i have now is the outputs this "The largest number you entered is: 3.5325e+27." instead of just an integer..

Comment: What was your input when you got that result?

Comment: Enter a positive number to start: 5
Enter integer: 7
Enter integer: 3
Enter integer: 4
Enter integer: 2
Enter integer: 4

The largest number you entered is: 3.5325e+27.

Comment: I've tested it on `C++ shell`. It works just fine.
Try to rebuild your whole project

Comment: Did you set `largest = 0` before rebuilding project? Like Havenard said, it's possible that uninitialized variables contain some random value (like 3.5325e+27) within that types range if not explicitly set to a value. In that case, the user input wasn't bigger than that huge value!

Comment: I figured out the solution. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 4):

You are constantly overwriting the value of `largest` with new input, where the variable `input` should be the one being used for that.
You check `if (input > largest)` and then replace `input` for the value of `largest`, which makes no sense at all.

You should instead read to `input`, and then replace the value of `largest` for the new `input` in case it is larger.

You should also initialize the variable `largest` so it doesn't start with some random memory garbage value that isn't even part of the inputs. You can make it start as `FLT_MIN` for instance to ensure that it will be overwritten by the first inputted value.

It also doesn't make sense to make decisions only `if (largest >= 0)`, this condition is only breaking the code.

In addition, you should indent your code properly for easy readability. The way it is now it's hard to tell where each code block starts and ends, this should be something you can determine just by glancing at the code, this mess makes debugging a very difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable called `input`, but when you take in input you're using the `largest` variable. Try making it be

```
cin >> input;
```

so that you store the input properly.

```
if (input > largest)
{
    input = largest;
}
```

This looks backwards, I think you want to  assign `largest` to be `input`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

In your only changes are

```
float largest;
float max_input;
float total = 0;
float input;
```

To

```
float largest=0;
float max_input=0;
float total = 0;
float input=0;
```

and

```
if (input > largest)
```

To 
`if (input < largest)`
and
 `cout << "\nThe largest number you entered is: " << largest << ".\n\n";`
 To
 `cout << "\nThe largest number you entered is: " << input << ".\n\n";`

final code will be,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
float largest=0;
float max_input;
float total = 0;
float input=0;
myDefault:  
cout << "Enter a positive number to start: ";
cin >> max_input;

if (max_input >= 0)
{
    total++;


        do {
            cout << "Enter integer: ";
            cin >> largest;

                if (largest >= 0)
                    {
                    total++;

                        if (input < largest)
                        {
                        input = largest;
                        }

            }
            }while (total <= max_input);

            cout << "\nThe largest number you entered is: " << input << ".\n\n";

}

else 
{
    cout << "Error. Enter a Positive number to start. \n";
    goto myDefault;

}

return (0);

}
```